# TypeError: (intermediate value).get is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, vite

```
import { Axios } from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function FetchData() {
  const [catFact, setCatFact] = useState('')
  
    useEffect(() => {
      Axios
        .get('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
        .then((res) => {
            setCatFact(res.data.fact);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{height:'100vh', display:'grid', placeItems:'center'}}>
      <article style={{padding: '3rem', width:'40rem'}}>
            <div className='grid'>
                <hgroup>
                  <h1>Preview</h1>
                  <h4>Generate facts about cats</h4>
                </hgroup>
                <button>Cat fact</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{catFact}</p>
            </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  )
}
```

when i ran the code the browers says,

TypeError: (intermediate value).get is not a function
The above error occurred in the  component:

FetchData@http://localhost:5173/src/components/FetchData.jsx:22:41
App

fetching data from a site using Axios

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the import (Remove the redundant braces `{}` ,it's the default export of the 'axios' module):

`import Axios from 'axios';`

see [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

In addition, place a semicolon after functions and variables declarations.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function FetchData() {
  const [catFact, setCatFact] = useState('');
  
    useEffect(() => {
      Axios
        .get('https://catfact.ninja/fact')
        .then((res) => {
            setCatFact(res.data.fact);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{height:'100vh', display:'grid', placeItems:'center'}}>
      <article style={{padding: '3rem', width:'40rem'}}>
            <div className='grid'>
                <hgroup>
                  <h1>Preview</h1>
                  <h4>Generate facts about cats</h4>
                </hgroup>
                <button>Cat fact</button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>{catFact}</p>
            </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What about `Axios` versus `axios`?

Comment: typo, just fixed.